# Access Object in Javascript Model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I fetch data from a model in Angular service , and in console log the data become like this.

```
console.log(serces);

alModel {info: Object}
    info: Object
    ProductName:"test product al"
    StartTime:"00:00:00"
    StopTime:"00:00:00"
    __proto__:Object
__proto__:Object
```

How do I to get the `ProductName` from there?

Please help, many thanks in advance.

Comment: `serces.ProductName` or `serces.alModel.ProductName`, I'm not positive what of the console you are showing.

Comment: Both is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

To access properties of an object, either use dot notation:

```
serces.ProductName
```

or bracket notation:

```
serces['ProductName']
```

Read away: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: Why the down vote?  Please explain how this doesn't address the question.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but encountered this while reviewing low quality answers.  Code-only answers are considered low quality content on StackOverflow, so the downvote is almost certainly because there's no explanation about why this solves the problem that the OP asked about.  Add an explanation and you'll be fine.  Note that if you continue answering and get zero or negative votes, you may be automatically banned from answering.  It's best to fix this and make sure that any other answers also have a suitable explanation.

Comment: Thank you, @MichaelGaskill.  I've fleshed out my answer further.